# xforms "instance namespace" issue

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, xforms

I am creating an Xform that reads an XML document and creates an input form for updating the document. However, apparently due to a namespace issue none of my Xpath expressions resolve.My form works fine on a simple instance when the instance file has no namespace.
However, I need the namespace support.

My instance file has a namespace "ai:inventory."

I am referencing the instance data

Where should I be declaring the prefix "ai" for my namespace so that my XPath expressions can find the appropriate elements?  /ai:inventory/products ?

I've tried creating the prefix in the html opening tag... that didn't help.

thanks,

Comment: Show us a very simple "instance" that still has the namespace issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally namespace declaration applies to current element and all descending elements. If you need to use the same namespace both in model and view, then html tag is a good choice. Something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:ai="yournamespace">
  <head>
    <xf:model>
      <xf:instance xmlns="">
        <ai:inventory>
          <product>Hello</product>
        </ai:inventory>
      </xf:instance>
    </xf:model>
  </head>
  <body>
    <xf:output ref="/ai:inventory/product"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that if you use non-namespaced elements in instance and also use XHTML as your default namespace, then you need to redeclare default namespace with xmlns="", as in example.

Answer (score 1):

An XForms instance is an XML document in its own right, so you should include appropriate namespace declarations for every instance in your form:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:ai="http://example.com/">
  <head>
    <xf:model>
      <xf:instance>
        <ai:inventory xmlns="" xmlns:ai="http://example.com/">
          <product>foo</product>
        </ai:inventory>
      </xf:instance>
    </xf:model>
  </head>
  <body>
    <xf:output ref="/ai:inventory/product"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are some processors that will evaluate the XPath correctly if your instance is inline (rather than an external resource), but I wouldn't recommend relying on that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers were corrected. However, I found that my issue was related to using the xsltforms xsl stylesheet to render my xform. when i switched to orbeon, everything worked fine.

Comment: Firefox is still not supporting the namespace axis and XSLTForms includes a (not perfect) workaround for namespaces. Adding a dummy element or attribute is even required in some cases.
Which browser are you using?